# UITextView link detect bug with iOS 8.3

Tags: hyperlink, uitextview, detect, ios8.3

I put into a non editable `UITextView` only one URL as string in order to make a link that work great until `iOS8.3`, set is :

```
myTextView.text = aLink;
```

First set is ok nice and link work well when touch, but another set will failed, text
is ok with the new url text, link is well detected with blue color but touch will always responds with first url as if `UITextView` be not uptaded.

Does I have to set another thing into `UITextView` ?

Comment: It's kind of hard to understand you, but it seems I am having the same/similar problem; **sometimes**, if having two urls inside one and the same uitextview, and having the link attributes set, all of the text in the uitextview gets the link attributes (in my case I use a different color, all of the text gets the link color, link or not). Also, all of the text becomes tappable as if all of the text was one big link with the url from the first link. The second URL is unreachable. tapping it will also open the first URL. Using iOS 11.2.5 (!)

Answer (score 2):

One solution:

Just after setting new string (with a link) I remove detection property:

```
self.myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

and trig *after* 0.1 second a new setting as:

```
self.myTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Works fine.

Comment: And, this fixes it for me, so +1 for this. Thanks. Btw, yes, looks like a bug in UITextView.

Answer (score 0):

I found a slightly alternative way that seems to fix it in my case. It avoids using a timer so the fix seems instant.

```
self.textviewText.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypes.init(rawValue: 0)
self.textviewText.text = newstring
self.textviewText.dataDetectorTypes = .link
```